# Is there a way to send optional parameters to an action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, optional-parameters

Can I send optional parameters (empty strings, null int?'s etc) to an action through a GET request in asp.net mvc? (one sentence question!)

Answer (score 2):

You can do optional parameters with the routing table fairly easily, just specify the defaults in the route of the global.cs file.

So for a search page with an optional query and page you would have something like

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new Route
{
    Url = "Search/[query]/[page]",
    Defaults = new { controller="Search", action="Results", page=1 },
    RouteHandler = typeof(MvcRouteHandler)
});
```

Default page for your search is then 1.

[This example is found here on Scott Gu's blog.](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx)

Comment: Yes, but how about my search url that has about 15 optional parameters. And optional doesn't mean with a default, it means optional.
I could off course agree on a certain term that my controller then discards when found.